# Cannot restore azure database to local due to missing master key

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure-sql-database

I create a bacpac from azure and restore to my local on-prem server. However, it throws an error like “Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation”. The reason is one of the column in the table is encrypted. I don’t know how to restore the database from azure with master key and certificate etc. Do you know what I could do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on encryption in SQL Server:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964742(v=sql.105).aspx
As well as key management:
https://goo.gl/ChhO7s
But really, the error message tells you everything, You need to create a master key:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337551.aspx
Or open the master key:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174433.aspx

Comment: The problem is how to open or create it before I restoring the database from azure successfully?  The database isn't exist yet!!!!

Comment: A BACPAC file isn't the same as a SQL Server Backup. It's actually just creating a database, then populating it with data. You can pre-create an empty database, create an encryption key, then import the BACPAC to create the schema & data within that database.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring a BACPAC isn't the same as restoring a SQL Server native backup (created using the `BACKUP DATABASE` syntax).

A native backup using `BACKUP DATABASE` is created by exporting all schema & data by backing up at the [page](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/08/22/data-pages-the-foundation-of-sql-server/) level into backup files. By convention, these generally have a .bak file extension. A `RESTORE DATABASE` does the inverse to create a database by copying the data pages out of the .bak and into the database. (It's a little more involved than this, but that's the big picture.) If the source database is encrypted with TDE, the data pages in the backup are also encrypted.

A BACPAC is created by generating `CREATE` statements for all of the schema, then doing an export of data. The .bacpac file itself is actually just a zip file of the `CREATE` scripts & data export. When doing a "restore" of the BACPAC, it simply executes the `CREATE` scripts, then does an import of the data. If the source database is encrypted with TDE, the exported data within the .bacpac file is *not* encrypted.

If you want to create a TDE-encrypted database using a BACPAC, simply pre-create an empty database and enable TDE on that database. Then, import the BACPAC into that empty database, and [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle).

Comment: In this answer and your comment you state "Then, import the BACPAC into that empty database". According to all documentation I can find this - importing bacpac into existing database - is not something that is possible. Can you elaborate please?